# groupedby_obj How to select and use data given under a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Code:

```
grouped_object = cov.groupby(["Continent"])
for key, item in grouped_obj:
    print('key is: ' + str(key))
```

Output:

```
key is: Africa
key is: Asia
key is: Europe
key is: Latin America and the Caribbean
key is: Northern America
key is: Oceania
```

I want to select data only under Africa for further processing, can any help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_group](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#selecting-a-group):

```py
africa_data = cov.groupby(["Continent"]).get_group("Africa")
```

You could also use [DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query):

```py
africa_data = cov.query("Continent == 'Africa'")
```